# Origin of the "to hit someone" definition of "clocked"

Tags: etymology

Google's second definition for "clock" is:

> *informal*
>
> hit (someone), especially on the head.
>
> "someone clocked him for no good reason"

What is the origin of this usage of the term?

Comment: http://etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=clock

Comment: I would guess it's combining "conked", "socked", and possibly some other terms.  Though there is the idiom "cleaned his clock", meaning worked him over pretty good.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The origin is from Australian slang of the 20's as  the following sources show. Etymonline suggests 1941 as the date of origin:

***[To clock](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/clock) (to hit/sock):***

> - To hit; sock: who clocked me when I wasn't looking/ She clocked him with the portable telephone (1920s+ Australian).(The Dictionary of American Slang, Fourth Edition)

***[To clock](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/clock):***

> - The verb sense ‘to punch or hit in the face’, first recorded in the 1920s, is ***originally Australian and comes from the slang use of clock to mean ‘a person's face’ ( see also dial).***  (ODO)

- Also [Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=clocked%20him%2Cclocked%20her&year_start=1900&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cclocked%20him%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cclocked%20her%3B%2Cc0) shows the possible date of origin the 1920's.

***[To clock](http://etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=clock)*** from Etymonline :

> - The slang sense of "hit, sock" is 1941, originally Australian, probably from earlier slang clock (n.)